# Highcharts 24 hours displayed on x axis

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I would like to show 24 hour days going across the Highcharts chart with 1 hour intervals on the x axis and 7 days on the y axis.

How do I get the chart to start at midnight and run for 24 hours across?

As you can see below the chart is currently starting at 8:00am and going until 3:00pm. Instead we would like it to start at 12:00am and end at 11:59pm.

[image]

```js
$('#graph').highcharts({
  exporting: { enabled: false },
  chart: {
    type: 'columnrange',
    inverted: true
  },
  title: {
    text:''
  },
  yAxis: {
    type: 'datetime',
    tickAmount: 24,
    tickInterval: 3600 * 1000,
    minTickInterval: 3600 * 1000,
    lineWidth: 1,
    dateTimeLabelFormats: {
        day: '%H:%M'
    },
    title: {
      enabled: false
    }
  },
  xAxis: {
    categories: ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday']
  },
  legend: {
    enabled: false
  },
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      pointWidth: 10,
    }
  },
  series: [{
    data: [
    {
      x: 0,
      low: Date.UTC(2010, 1, 1, 9, 0, 0),
      high: Date.UTC(2010, 1, 1, 12, 0, 0),
      color: 'blue'
    }, {
      x: 0,
      low: Date.UTC(2010, 1, 1, 12, 30, 0),
      high: Date.UTC(2010, 1, 1, 14, 0, 0),
      color: 'blue'
    },

    {
      x: 1,
      low: Date.UTC(2010, 1, 2, 9, 0, 0),
      high: Date.UTC(2010, 1, 2, 12, 0, 0),
      color: 'blue'
    },
    {
      x: 2,
      low: Date.UTC(2010, 1, 3, 9, 0, 0),
      high: Date.UTC(2010, 1, 3, 12, 0, 0),
      color: 'blue'
    },
    {
      x: 3,
      low: Date.UTC(2010, 1, 4, 9, 0, 0),
      high: Date.UTC(2010, 1, 4, 12, 0, 0),
      color: 'blue'
    },
    {
      x: 4,
      low: Date.UTC(2010, 1, 5, 9, 0, 0),
      high: Date.UTC(2010, 1, 5, 12, 0, 0),
      color: 'blue'
    },
    {
      x: 5,
      low: Date.UTC(2010, 1, 6, 9, 0, 0),
      high: Date.UTC(2010, 1, 6, 12, 0, 0),
      color: 'blue'
    },
    {
      x: 6,
      low: Date.UTC(2010, 1, 7, 9, 0, 0),
      high: Date.UTC(2010, 1, 7, 12, 0, 0),
      color: 'blue'
    },

    ]
  }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>


<div id="graph"></div>
```

----------------EDIT----------------
I updated the data to replicate what we actually want. The output is working but "broken". We would like the graph to look like the picture.

Answer (score 3):

You can use yAxis.min and yAxis.max for setting the min and max values of your axis. You can use tickPositioner for setting the positions of your labels on axis:
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.tickPositioner

```
yAxis: {
  min: Date.UTC(2010, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0),
  max: Date.UTC(2010, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0),
  type: 'datetime',
  tickPositioner: function() {
    var info = this.tickPositions.info;
    var positions = [];
    for (i = Date.UTC(2010, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0); i <= Date.UTC(2010, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0); i += 3600 * 1000) {
      positions.push(i);
    }
    positions.info = info;
    return positions;
  },
  lineWidth: 1,
  dateTimeLabelFormats: {
    day: '%H:%M'
  },
  title: {
    enabled: false
  }
},
```

Here you can see an example how it can work:
http://jsfiddle.net/1yccghgy/1/

Comment: Thank you! This works great. We saw a answer to a different question/answer that suggested using the min and max values like you did. Are there any negatives that you can think of to hard coding the min and max values?

Comment: I realized my data was invalid and therefore hardcoding dates into the min and max cause the graph to not plot my data.

Comment: Yes, I think that sometimes better may be to use setExtremes in your xAxis and yAxis, because you may not know the range you want to display in your chart before you will load your chart. But in your case it should be fine. Is my example working for you? If yes, could you mark my answer as correct?

Comment: Any idea for this.tickPositions.info; I can't find this **info** property in Highcharts.

Comment: It is not a documented property. However, as you can read directly in Highcharts code: "// record information on the chosen unit - for dynamic label formatter"